# Clarification on raster::adjacent() output values:

Tags: r, gis, raster

I am trying to create a rooks case adjacency matrix using raster::adjacent(), but I am having trouble understanding the output.

Reproducible Example:

```
library(raster)

r <- raster(nrow = 3, ncol = 3)

rAdjacent <- raster::adjacent(r, cells = 1:ncell(r), pairs = TRUE, directions = 4) 

rAdjacent
      from to
 [1,]    1  3
 [2,]    2  1
 [3,]    3  2
 [4,]    4  6
...
```

From my interpretation of the output, the output says that 1 and 3 have a rooks case relationship (and if I understand this type of relationship correctly, they do not).

Question 1. Is this correct? Am I interpreting this output correctly?

Question 2. How do I create an output using adjacent() or something else that gives me pairs of adjacent cell numbers?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to project your raster.

> The function connects the outer meridians if the raster is not
>   projeced (in a geographic (lat/lon) "projection") and there is data at
>   longitudes -180 and 180 degrees. (from [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/1.0.4/topics/adjacency)).

```
r <- raster(nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
crs(r) <- CRS("+proj=robin +datum=WGS84")

rAdjacent <- raster::adjacent(r, cells = 1:ncell(r), 
                              pairs = TRUE, directions = 4) 
rAdjacent[order(rAdjacent[,1]),]
```

> ```
>       from to
>  [1,]    1  2
>  [2,]    1  4
>  [3,]    2  1
>  [4,]    2  3
>  [5,]    2  5
>  [6,]    3  2
>  [7,]    3  6
>  [8,]    4  5
>  [9,]    4  1
> [10,]    4  7
> [11,]    5  4
> [12,]    5  6
> [13,]    5  2
> [14,]    5  8
> [15,]    6  5
> [16,]    6  3
> [17,]    6  9
> [18,]    7  8
> [19,]    7  4
> [20,]    8  7
> [21,]    8  9
> [22,]    8  5
> [23,]    9  8
> [24,]    9  6
> ```

Comment: Great answer. This is so much simpler than any one of my elaborate workarounds. Thank you!